# How do you call to a previous function?

Tags: programming

I'm using an Arduino to control a reverse osmosis machine, I would like after a certain number low pressure events to return to the testing routine. Can you call to previous functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your head around the Finite State Machine (FSM).

It is a programming method which allows your program ("Machine") to be in any of a certain number ("Finite") of states ("State").  One state would be reading pressure. Another state would be "testing", or whatever.

I wrote a tutorial ages ago about it: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/finite-state-machine

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "previous"? In the call stack or in the code?
Either way, you can call any (public|member|static) function you want at any time, even call the very same function you're already in (recursion, but not recommended on Arduino or any other embedded system).

Comment: fsm does seem like a good way to handle it. your tutorial is very easy to follow

Comment: by previous, I mean  I had a void testing routine that once voltage reading in met it goes to  void main run I was trying to get it to  read a  high/low signal and after 2 cycles of reading low i wanted it to go back to void testing.

Comment: Ok, I see. To me it sounds like you should read up on the basics of programming, before posting questions here.